# ASP.NET postgresql NpgsqlDbType.Bit doesn't support BitArray?

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, parameters, bit, bitarray

Running into a type bug that seems to contradict the docs...

Created a postgresql tabel on my local computer with 2 columns (SystemID [as uuid], TrackingIDs [as Bit[] with size 256]).

In C# ASP.NET I'm getting the error:

> 42804: column "TrackingIDs" is of type bit[] but expression is of type
>   bit

I see no option for "NpgsqlDbType.BitArray" but the docs say "NpgsqlDbType.Bit" should accept a C# BitArray object type: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html

Here is an example of my C# code:

```
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(DBUtils.connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO hosts VALUES(@SystemID, @TrackingIDs)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SystemID", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid, systemID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrackingIDs", NpgsqlDbType.Bit, new BitArray(256));
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() != 0 ? "Success" : "Failed";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

pgAdmin4: 3.6
Npgsql version: 4.0.4
PostgreSQL version: 11.1
Operating system: Win10 x64
ASP.NET: .NET Core 2.2

**EDIT: Was missing "NpgsqlDbType.Bit | NpgsqlDbType.Array". However I now just get:**

> 22026: bit string length 1 does not match type bit(256)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So bit in PostgreSQL can be any size or can be thought of as plural. Was thinking in terms of a bit from a byte for example. So the solution is to just create a "bit" type column with a length of 256. Then I can set a BitArray(256) to it.